# DD-WRT admin page redirects to 192.168.11.1 after changing its IP

Tags: dd-wrt

I'm running three DD-WRT routers. One acts as the external gateway and does NAT and DHCP, and the two others are connected via Ethernet and act as wifi bridges (via [these instructions](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Wireless_Access_Point)). It works great!

The main router has an IP of 10.0.1.1, and the other two 10.0.1.2 and 10.0.1.3 respectively, which is defined in the Basic Setup:

[image: basic setup]

I can go to http://10.0.1.1/ to administer the main router, but if I go to http://10.0.1.2/ or http://10.0.1.3/, I get redirected to the router's manufacturer default IP of 192.168.11.1:

```
$ curl -i http://10.0.1.2
HTTP/1.0 302 Found
Content-Type:
Server: httpd
Connection: close
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Location: http://192.168.11.1/detect.asp
```

If I telnet into the two bridges, they appear to show the correct IP:

```
root@bridge1:~# nvram get lan_ipaddr
10.0.1.2
```

**Do you know why the router's web administration page is redirecting to the wrong IP?**

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.

1. I'm using Buffalo DD-WRT routers, which have some [special code](http://svn.dd-wrt.com/browser/src/router/httpd/httpd.c?rev=22412#L774) to show a Setup Assistant
2. Going to http://10.0.1.2/detect.asp and http://10.0.1.3/detect.asp (if the URL ends with `detect.asp` it doesn't get redirected) and letting the Setup Assistant actually finish, then clicking Apply, seems to fix it.

I also tried `nvram set ias_startup=0`, `nvram set ias_setup_running=0`, `nvram commit` and `reboot` -- that might have had an effect.

Comment: Must be a new feature, I have a few Buffalo DD-WRTs and none has it.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae FWIW, these are all Buffalo N600's running `DD-WRT v24SP2-MULTI (11/04/12) std`